# Convert beautiful list output to string

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a site for some stats and getting the results as expected, but I can't get the final list output into a string. Searched and tried everything I can find... `strip()`, `append()`, `replace('\n')`, `replace('\n\t\r')`, and a few dozen other things. And, I get an output error at the end as there are some additional items in list I don't want.

Output I get:

```
81
79
55
12
76
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Output I want:

```
81 79 55 12 76
```

Here is a sample of what I am scraping:

```
</li>, <li><span class="bp3-tag p p-81">81</span> f1</span>
</li>, <li><span class="bp3-tag p p-79">79</span> f2</span>
</li>, <li><span class="bp3-tag p p-55">55</span> f3</span>
</li>, <li><span class="bp3-tag p p-12">12</span> f4</span>
</li>, <li><span class="bp3-tag p p-76">76</span> f5</span>
[<li><span class="tooltip multiline" data-tooltip="some text i don't care about.">
```

My code looks like this, where a_stats is the list of fields being searched (f1, f2, ...)

```
dws = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'col-3'})
more_lis = [div.find_all('li') for div in dws]
lis = soup.find_all('li') + more_lis
for li in lis:
       for stats in a_stats:
           if stats in li.text:
                t = re.findall('\d+', li.text)
                ti = (" ".join(t))
                print(ti)
```

I'm very much a novice, and this feels like it should be easy but I just can't get there yet. Help appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `print(t1)` try `print(t1, end=" ")`

**EDIT**

```py
dws = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'col-3'})
more_lis = [div.find_all('li') for div in dws]
lis = soup.find_all('li') + more_lis
for li in lis:
       for stats in a_stats:
           try:
               if stats in li.text:
                   t = re.findall('\d+', li.text)
                   ti = (" ".join(t))
                   print(ti)
           except AttributeError:
               pass
```

Added try and except block to handle `AttributeError`

---

The end argument in print decides what should follow after the object is printed. By default it is `\n` so you get the new line. Change it to a while space like `" "` and that should be it.

Comment: Close! got the integers as desired, but it's still throwing the attribute error for the unwanted tooltip... Any thoughts?

Comment: @mayord kindly provide the exact line no where you are encountering the error

Comment: It's in line 6: 'if stats in li.text:'

Comment: I have made changes to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example based on reading the HTML from a file. The changes needed for your use-case should be obvious:-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('/Users/andy/dummy.html') as html:
    vals = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-3')
    for div in divs:
        for li in div.find_all('li'):
            vals.append(li.text+' ')
    print(''.join(vals))
```